# how to consolidate multiple function call to once call with different parameters for the same func

Tags: python

Python
I have one function let us say: `def func(para1,para2,para3)`

I have such if else condition:

```py
if condition_1:
    para1, para2, para3 = 1, 2, 3
    func(para1, para2, para3)
else:
    for para1, para2, para3 in [
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9],
        ...,
    ]:
        func(para1, para2, para3)
```

the `func` here call multiple times.

what I want is to call the same function once at the end of the block.

```py
if condition_1:
    ...
else:
    ...

func(para1, para2, para3)  # call once
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to consolidate single call to multiple call, instead of opposite.

```py
if condition_1:
    params = [(1, 2, 3)]  # [[1, 2, 3]] is OK.
else:
    params = [
        (4, 5, 6),  # [4, 5, 6] is OK.
        (7, 8, 9),
        # ...
    ]

for param in params:
    func(*param)
```